Curve Modifier problem while making a Rolling banner for VFX Video
I was trying to create a VFX video have a rolling banner on a building  and now I have a problem regarding the Curve modifier.
I already subdivided the plane and set origin to geometry , applied all , when I am trying to make the plane roll on the object, it's not rolling at all or rolling on different direction at all.
Anyone knows the reason behind that and how to fix it?
I am following this tutorial
https://youtu.be/75HJKMdTpc0?si=doo4cMJ8cntzrNfj



Without having your file to inspect, it is really hard to tell just from a few screenshots. But honestly, you are watching a tutorial where it works, so I assume that like in many other cases here the problem is, you did not follow the tutorial thoroughly enough and missed something. I always recommend watching the tutorial again and paying close attention to hwat they are doing there. Another possibility is, since you are using a different version than the tutorial, some things might work different now. But you cannot expect us to do a complete tutorial to see where the versions differ.

please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
